# Multiple pool options in Antminer S9 Settings

Tags: mining-pools, antminer

I have purchased and got running Antminer S9. While setting it up I notices that I can specify three pool connections

[image]

I was unable to find the purpose for this.

Are those backup options just in case one or two pool connections are down or should I could actually mine for three pools at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AntMiner S9 manual is available at https://shop.bitmain.com/files/download/AntMiner%20S9%20Installation%20Guide.pdf

The manual says:

> The AntMiner S9 can be set up with three mining pools, with decreasing
>   priority from the first pool (pool 1) to the third pool (pool 3).
>
> The pools with low priority will only be used if all higher priority
>   pools are offline.

On older S-series models there used to be a "Pool Balance" setting on the pool screen, below the "pool 1", "pool 2", "pool 3" in your screenshot. From the manual for the old S3:

> AntMiner can set up three mine pools, the priority decreases from
>   first pool (pool 1) to third pool (pool 3). There are three Pool
>   Balance option:
>
> Failover: Automatic backup when Miner faults;
>   ‘Failover’ is by default. The low priority pool will start to work,
>   only when the high priority pool encounter fault.
>
> Balance: Change
>   multipool strategy from failover to even share balance.
>
> Load Balance:
>   Change multipool strategy from failover to quota based balance.

I do not know why this feature was removed in later models.